# Optimize binomial distribution where counts are >170

Tags: r, optimization

How can I minimize binomial distribution when the some values are more than 170. In this case the factorial function returns Inf. please see followings two examples. In the first case all things are OK:

Case 1:

```
        n<-c(100,103,170,100)  
        k<-c(85,86,112,84) 
        DF<-data.frame(n,k)

        BINO<-function(pii,data) {    

          A= log((factorial(n)/ (factorial(k)*factorial(n-k)) ) *(pii^k)*(1-pii)^(n-k) )

          cat( pii, '\n')
          flush.console()
         sum(abs(A))
        }
     library(bbmle)      
     mle2(BINO, start=list(pii=0.1), data=DF)

        Coefficients:
              pii 
        0.7758984 

    Log-likelihood: -19.59
```

But in case 2 where two counts (226 and 183) are more than 170, calculation is failed.

Case 2:

```
    n<-c(100,103,226,100)  
    k<-c(85,86,183,84) 
    DF<-data.frame(n,k)

    mle2(BINO, start=list(pii=0.1), data=DF)

0.1 
Error in optim(par = 0.1, fn = function (p)  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In factorial(n) : value out of range in 'gammafn'
2: In factorial(k) : value out of range in 'gammafn'
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the `dbinom` function and check its `log` argument that allows to handle very big `n` and `k`.

Comment: I think dbinom can not resolve this problem, if it possible let me know how you can optimise pii with dbinom in case 2. thank you...

Comment: Just define `A = dbinom(k,n,pii,log=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks nicola I defined **A = dbinom(k,n,pii,log=TRUE)** and it worked properly. For other distributions also I had reinvented the wheel!!!. I should redefined all. Thanks again....

Comment: Dear nicole do you have a recommendation on how can I obtain the confidence interval for pii in this example. Thank you.